# Search in Multiple Indexes

Tags: elastic4s

When I do a search is it possible to search across multiple indexes? I know we could create an alias, but I would rather not have to do that for my given use case. the "search in index1" works great.  Was just hoping I could do something like "search in index1/index2".

Probably user error, but can't find any info about it.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.  I should have realized the syntax before.

If you put the condition as follows it seems to work.

```
search in ("Index1","Index2")
```

Hope this helps someone else.

--S

Comment: What you can't do is search in "all", that's something we'll add.